# How do I prepopulate image on knex migration and seed using db-browser for SQLite?

Tags: knex.js, db-browser-sqlite

I am trying to prepopulate image using knex migration and seed. I am also using DB browser for SQLite. Here is what I have so far.

```
exports.up = function(knex, Promise) {
  return knex.schema.createTable('shows', function(shows) {
    shows.increments();

    shows.string('title', 30)
      .notNullable();
    shows.binary('img_url', 250)
      .notNullable();

    shows.integer('user_id')
      .unsigned()
      .references('id')
      .inTable('users');

    shows.integer('genre_id')
      .unsigned()
      .references('id')
      .inTable('genres');
  });
};

exports.down = function(knex, Promise) {
  return knex.schema.dropTableIfExists('shows');
};
```

```
exports.seed = function(knex, Promise) {
  // Deletes ALL existing entries
  return knex('shows').truncate()
    .then(function () {
      // Inserts seed entries
      return knex('shows').insert([
        {title: 'Avengers: Endgame', img_url: 'https://i.ebayimg.com/thumbs/images/g/ocMAAOSwgaxcrKUL/s-l96.jpg', user_id: 1, genre_id: 1},
        {title: 'Spider-Man: Into the Spider-Verse', img_url: 'https://img00.deviantart.net/08d6/i/2019/046/9/6/spiderman_into_the_spiderverse_v2_by_edgina36-dcztwdn.png', user_id: 1, genre_id: 2},
        {title: 'Game of Thrones', img_url: 'https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/51Ep4em2vxL._AA256_.jpg', user_id: 1, genre_id: 6},
        {title: 'Fresh off the Boat', img_url: 'https://www.sdcitytimes.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/fotb.jpg', user_id: 2, genre_id: 6},
        {title: 'Men in Black 2', img_url: 'http://www.sonypicturesmuseum.com/public/uploads/collectionasset/image/men-in-black-2-POSTER-1@2x.jpg', user_id: 2, genre_id: 2},
        {title: 'The Lion King', img_url: 'https://c-sf.smule.com/sf/s36/arr/39/6c/9a1d94ef-c13f-4b9c-894c-c3b96db436ca.jpg', user_id: 3, genre_id: 7},
        {title: 'Incredibles 2', img_url: 'https://thecinephiliac.files.wordpress.com/2018/07/incre.jpg?w=336&h=498', user_id: 3, genre_id: 7},
        {title: 'Crazy Rich Asians', img_url: 'https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/61HR6PAdDYL._AA256_.jpg', user_id: 4, genre_id: 3},
        {title: 'The Rookie', img_url: 'https://cdn.technadu.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/The-Rookie-696x392.png', user_id: 5, genre_id: 5},
        {title: 'Line of Duty', img_url: 'https://pics.filmaffinity.com/line_of_duty_tv_series-605974923-large.jpg', user_id: 5, genre_id: 4},
      ]);
    });
};
```

But instead of it showing the image on the front end, it gives me the link.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could provide the way you want to consume the image on the front end. passing the img_url value to an image tag should work.